# C# - Emgu CV Retireve and display calculated Eigenfaces and Average faces on the GUI(Picture box or image box)

Tags: c#, wrapper, emgucv, face-recognition

I was trying to study Face Recognition using Emgu CV wrapper in C#.I did the recognition fine.What i just want to know is how i do retrieve the calculated Eigenfaces and Average faces in a picture box.Can anyone show me how i do this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

after calling MCvTermCriteria and EigenObjectRecognizer, write this
ibAvg.Image = recognizer.AverageImage;